# How does the Qiskit AerSimulator performance scale with the circuit depth?

Tags: simulation, performance, qiskit

The performance of a full-statevector simulation by the Qiskit [AerSimulator](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/aer/stubs/qiskit_aer.AerSimulator.html) scales of course exponentially with the number of qubits, since the dimensionality of the Hilbert space where an $N$-qubits state is living grows as $2^N$.

But how does the performance scale with the circuit depth and why? Is there any standard study about it released by Qiskit/IBM Quantum themselves?

Answer (score 3):

From my point of view, in the worst case, the computational cost scales linearly with the depth of the circuit. The math behind quantum computer simulation is linear algebra and matrix manipulations on the quantum state vector. So, each layer of the gate requires a $2^N$ by $2^N$ matrix multiplying a $2^N$-dimension state vector. Consequently, the computational cost growth linearly with the depth of the circuit.